# XeTeX is printing explicit space characters inside quoted strings

Tags: xetex, listings, spanish

I'm using XeLaTeX with this:

```
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
```

But when I write this listing

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Pyshell]
>>> print "¿Cómo se llama?"
¿Cómo se llama? 
>>> nombre = input()
Pepe
>>> print "Me alegro de conocerle,", nombre
Me alegro de conocerle, Pepe
\end{lstlisting}
```

I got this as result:

```
>>> print "¿Cómo ␣se␣ llama ?"
¿Cómo se llama ?
>>> nombre = input ()
Pepe
>>> print "Me␣ alegro ␣de␣conocerle ,", nombre
Me alegro de conocerle , Pepe
```

How does I avoid this "␣" printing? It only appears when quoted text are inside listings, my customized listing is based on Python like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{Pyshell}
{language=Python,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
morekeywords={>>>},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a global setting of `showstringspaces` anywhere. Add this to your definition of `Pyshell`:

```
showstringspaces=false
```

Comment: The setting `showstringspaces=true` is global for `listings`.